# ssh: HOME variable issue

Tags: ssh

I'm in Cyanogenmod 13 and I'm having troubles getting ssh working properly.

Server:
With `AuthorizedKeysFile` commented in the `sshd_config` file, I get a weird path in logcat:

```
Could not open authorized keys '//.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

I set `AuthorizedKeysFile` and the server seems to work with no more problems.

Still I cannot get the client working:

```
root@i9300:/ # ssh 192.168.0.20
Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.20 (192.168.0.20)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
```

As you can see ssh is trying to create the directory `/`, and we all know that it is not possible.
All of this led me to the conclusion that there might be something wrong with the environment variable `HOME`.

Another piece of information:

```
root@i9300:/ # echo $HOME
/data
root@i9300:/ # su shell
shell@i9300:/ $ echo $HOME
/
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try storing the identity file somewhere in /sdcard/ and use `-i IDENTITY_FILE` and provide config using -F. $HOME is perfectly fine. Permissions on `/data` are beyond the privilege shell user can have.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord, it works! `ssh 192.168.0.20 -i /data/.ssh/id_rsa` does the job. I'd be very happy if someone could tell me where a template for ssh_config file is, it doesn't seem to exist. The problem of creating `/.ssh/known_hosts` remains. I managed a workaround creating the symlink `/.ssh -> /data/.ssh/`. It is not possible to create it by shell/script because I get error `Read-only file system` (even with `/system` mounted rw). I did manage with CMFileManager, and I wish I knew how it has done it!! `/.ssh` will disappear at every boot and I'd like to create a script to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solid workaround which requires a bit of work if you are not accustomed with the subject:
Edit `BOOT` partition.

In the `BOOT` partition (`boot.img`) are stored all the files that will be loaded in `/` at boot.
I added a symlink in it:

```
.ssh -> /data/.ssh
```

Here are two very helpful tutorials that will get you going:
[HOWTO: Unpack, Edit, and Repack Boot Images](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=443994)
[Android boot.img manipulation](http://k.japko.eu/boot-img-manipulation.html)

a little hint:
Do edit the ramdisk in your Android device.
I spent three days in frustration trying to do so in my pc, I guess is a matter of "endianness".